# Locking rows behaviour for a temporary table in a PLPGSQL function

Tags: sql, postgresql, concurrency, triggers, plpgsql

I have two tables in my DB: my source of truth table (call it table A) and a denormalized table (call it table B).

A row in table A, will have a column `status` that is a `BOOLEAN`, and table B only contains a row if the `status` in table A is `true`.

Since table B is a new addition to my DB, I need to populate it from the already-existing data in table A. I use a PLPGSQL function to do that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION backfill_single_batch() AS
$$
...
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp ON COMMIT DROP AS
    SELECT ...
    FROM tableA
    WHERE status IS TRUE
    FOR UPDATE;

CREATE TEMP TABLE inserted_rows ON COMMIT DROP AS
    WITH ins AS (
        INSERT INTO tableB
            SELECT * FROM temp
            ON CONFLICT (..) DO NOTHING
            RETURNING *)
    SELECT *
    FROM ins;
...
```

Note the `FOR UPDATE` in the first query. I believe this is needed so that if a row changes from `TRUE` to `FALSE` after the first `CREATE TEMP`, I do not want to insert it.

Meanwhile, of course, I have a trigger that deletes rows from tableB whenever a status is updated from `TRUE` to `FALSE`. Here it is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION on_status_update()
    RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    IF OLD.status IS TRUE AND NEW.status IS FALSE THEN
        DELETE FROM tableB WHERE ...;
    ELSIF OLD.status IS FALSE AND NEW.status IS TRUE THEN
        INSERT INTO table B (...)
        SELECT ...
        FROM tableA
        WHERE ...
        ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_on_status_update
    AFTER UPDATE ON tableA
    FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION on_status_update();
```

**The issue now:**

I am seeing rows with status `FALSE` being inserted by my PLPGSQL function *after* they were removed by the trigger.

So the sequence of this is:

1. A row is updated to `FALSE`
2. Trigger kicks in and deletes the row from table B
3. My PLPGSQL function, running at the same time, still thinks that that particular row should be inserted in table B, and ends up inserting the spurious row, resulting in incorrect state.

What am I doing wrong here? I would have expected that the `FOR UPDATE` in my function would be enough to guard against this scenario, as these rows would be locked until the function executes but evidently not.

Comment: Temporary table is visible just from current session. The locks there has not any sense.

Comment: @PavelStehule are you saying that the `FOR UPDATE` in my code actually locks the temporary table and not `tableA`?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe it's more about if locking `tableA` while creating the temp table works as I expect. Am I misunderstanding something here? I was counting on `FOR UPDATE` locking the rows that I selected from `tableA` (and then insert into the temp table).

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe suspending modifications is not an option unfortunately. Are you saying that the locking behaviour does not work as I expect, though? Do you see an issue with above code?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Why would I lock other `FALSE` rows? I don't want to insert these in tableB. And if a row changes from `FALSE` to `TRUE`, it will get picked up by the trigger.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Is my understanding correct that between the `FOR UPDATE` and the function completing, the rows that I lock in tableA would never be changed concurrently? That's really the key thing here. And in the same way: am I guaranteed that the `SELECT FOR UPDATE` will read the very latest state of the rows, including those about to be modifier?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe yes, that is the case indeed. Quite strange thing here. If I were to lock all of tableA for the duration of the function, what approach would you recommend? I would only need to lock it for writes not reads.

Comment: I think I may have realised the issue: the default isolation level is not strict enough for me. If a transaction updated rows and still has not committed them just before my `SELECT FOR UPDATE`, I will see the old state of the rows.

Comment: @msamyatl No, that can't happen. If another transaction started modifying the rows, your SELECT FOR UPDATE will wait on a lock regardless of isolation level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you define the trigger *before* you start your script for the already existing data, the inconsistency you describe cannot happen.

One shortcoming in your setup is that you are missing triggers for `INSERT` and `DELETE`.

Your bulk update procedure could be greatly simplified:

```
WITH truerows AS (
   SELECT * FROM tablea
   WHERE bool
   FOR SHARE
)
INSERT INTO tableb
SELECT * FROM truerows;
```

A `SHARE` lock is sufficient to prevent concurrent data modifications.

Comment: Thanks for confirming the code above was correct. Indeed, my problem turned out to be elsewhere. Appreciate the help.